# Split up a text file based on its contents

Tags: python, file, parsing, text, split

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
SYSTEM

DOF=UY,UZ,RX  LENGTH=FT  FORCE=Kip

JOINT
  1  X=0  Y=-132.644  Z=0
  2  X=0  Y=-80  Z=0
  3  X=0  Y=-40  Z=0
  4  X=0  Y=0  Z=0
  5  X=0  Y=40  Z=0
  6  X=0  Y=80  Z=0
  7  X=0  Y=132.644  Z=0
```

etc. for 10,000 joints.

I would like to write a script that reads this text file and outputs 4 text files that are 1 column each containing the joint number, x coordinate, y coordinate, and z coordinate.

Is this possible? I am new to python and tried something like this but Python doesn't know what to do with System in the text file and I'm sure my method isn't correct:

```
os.chdir('/Users/DevEnv/')

with open('RawDataFile_445.txt') as a:
    for line in a.readlines():
        j=[]
        data=line.strip()
        data1=data.split(" ")
        for i in range(0,len(data1)):
            j.append(eval(data1[i]))
        joint=j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seemed fragile:

- you have to filter headers, non-data lines
- you use `eval()` which is really overkill and unsafe.
- using `readlines()` can be very memory-hungry: reads all data in memory, you don't need to do that. Just read one line at a time.
- you miss the code to write back to the output files

My solution uses regular expressions to extract all data in one go. Comments in the code:

```
import re

# regex to extract data line    
r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+X=(\S+)\s+Y=(\S+)\s+Z=(\S+)")

with open('RawDataFile_445.txt') as a:

    # open all 4 files with a meaningful name
    files=[open("file_{}.txt".format(x),"w") for x in ["J","X","Y","Z"]]
    for line in a:
        m = r.match(line)
        if m:
            # line matches: write in all 4 files (using zip to avoid doing
            # it one by one)
            for f,v in zip(files,m.groups()):
                f.write(v+"\n")

    # close all output files now that it's done
    for f in files:
        f.close()
```

you can test it by replacing the `with open(...) as a:` bit by:

```
a="""SYSTEM

DOF=UY,UZ,RX  LENGTH=FT  FORCE=Kip

JOINT
  1  X=0  Y=-132.644  Z=0
  2  X=0  Y=-80  Z=0
  3  X=0  Y=-40  Z=0
  4  X=0  Y=0  Z=0
  5  X=0  Y=40  Z=0
  6  X=0  Y=80  Z=0
  7  X=0  Y=132.644  Z=0""".splitlines().__iter__()
```

emulating the input file lines (that's how I do to answer questions with input files, to avoid creating input files on my system). You'll see the 4 files are created and filled up (don't forget the `close` part at the end of the code)

Comment: This is working really well, although it only reads the first line of the text file

Comment: you accepted the answer (thanks for that). It means that it works for you after all? (I have tested it, it works all the way down to the last input file line). If there's a problem, let me know, I hate leaving non-working upvoted/accepted stuff around :)

Comment: It definitely seems correct but now when I run it the J, X,Y,Z text files are all empty. I must be doing something wrong but if you could help that would be great

Comment: check my edit. I have added a self-test which doesn't require an input file (which I cannot check in detail, maybe your copy paste misses something, you figure it out, I can't)

Comment: maybe your input file has an invisible "feature" that I cannot figure out. Maybe you could link it so I can check it (free of charge, you already accepted the answer :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130443/discussion-between-user7269405-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xlist, ylist, zlist = [], [], []
for line in file.readlines():
    try:
        if line.strip()[0].isdigit():
                s = line.split("=")
                x, y, z = (float(s[i][:-1].strip()) for i in range(1, 4))
                xlist.append(x)
                ylist.append(y)
                zlist.append(z)
    except:
        pass
```

This will do it for every line that starts with a number. Note: without empty lines, you have no need for the try statement.