# Splitting text with python

Tags: python, text, split

I have a python script that reads a list of text and writes it to four seperate files. Would it be possible to just write one text file where each line has the joint coordinate x coordinate y coordinate and z coordinate separated by spaces? I would greatly appreciate any help

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/JP/DevEnv/ASA')


import re

# regex to extract data line    
r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+X=(\S+)\s+Y=(\S+)\s+Z=(\S+)")

a="""SYSTEM

    DOF=UY,UZ,RX  LENGTH=FT  FORCE=Kip

    JOINT
    1  X=0  Y=-132.644  Z=0
    2  X=0  Y=-80  Z=0
    3  X=0  Y=-40  Z=0
    4  X=0  Y=0  Z=0
    5  X=0  Y=40  Z=0
    6  X=0  Y=80  Z=0
    7  X=0  Y=132.644  Z=0""".splitlines().__iter__()

    # open all 4 files with a meaningful name
    files=[open("file_{}.txt".format(x),"w") for x in ["J","X","Y","Z"]]
    for line in a:
        m = r.match(line)
        if m:
            # line matches: write in all 4 files (using zip to avoid doing
            # it one by one)
            for f,v in zip(files,m.groups()):
                f.write(v+"\n")

    # close all output files now that it's done
    for f in files:
        f.close()
```

The first line of the output text file would look like this: 
    1 0 -132.644 0

Comment: I cannot undestand what you want lines of a single output file to look like and how it would be different from the input file.  Show what it should be for the input you give.

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109713/split-up-a-text-file-based-on-its-contents

Comment: Well that was my question from earlier but now I'm trying to do something different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
a="""SYSTEM

    DOF=UY,UZ,RX  LENGTH=FT  FORCE=Kip

    JOINT
    1  X=0  Y=-132.644  Z=0
    2  X=0  Y=-80  Z=0
    3  X=0  Y=-40  Z=0
    4  X=0  Y=0  Z=0
    5  X=0  Y=40  Z=0
    6  X=0  Y=80  Z=0
    7  X=0  Y=132.644  Z=0"""
# replace all character except digit, '-', '.' and ' '(space) with nothing, get all the info you need, than split each info into a list
b = re.sub(r'[^\d\. -]','',a).split() 
# split the list to sublists, each contain four elements 
lines = [b[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

out:

```
['1', '0', '-132.644', '0']
['2', '0', '-80', '0']
['3', '0', '-40', '0']
['4', '0', '0', '0']
['5', '0', '40', '0']
['6', '0', '80', '0']
['7', '0', '132.644', '0']
```

or write to file:

```
print(' '.join(line),file=open('youfilename', 'a'))
```

or:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
    # or
    f.writelines(' '.join(line)+'\n' for line in lines)
```

out:

```
1 0 -132.644 0
2 0 -80 0
3 0 -40 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 40 0
6 0 80 0
7 0 132.644 0
```

Comment: This solution is working but what if I wanted to output the results to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want a file with everything excepts numbers and spaces eliminated.  Here are two solutions, one using REs, one not.

```
a="""SYSTEM

    DOF=UY,UZ,RX  LENGTH=FT  FORCE=Kip

    JOINT
    1  X=0  Y=-132.644  Z=0
    2  X=0  Y=-80  Z=0
    3  X=0  Y=-40  Z=0
    4  X=0  Y=0  Z=0
    5  X=0  Y=40  Z=0
    6  X=0  Y=80  Z=0
    7  X=0  Y=132.644  Z=0""".splitlines()

for line in a:
    line = line.strip()
    if line and line[0].isdecimal():
        print((''.join(c for c in line if c.isdecimal() or c in '- .')
                .replace('  ', ' ')))

print()
import re
r = re.compile(r"\s*(\d+)\s+X=(\S+)\s+Y=(\S+)\s+Z=(\S+)")
for line in a:
    m = r.match(line)
    if m:
        print(' '.join(n for n in m.groups()))
```

This prints the following twice

```
1 0 -132.644 0
2 0 -80 0
3 0 -40 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 40 0
6 0 80 0
7 0 132.644 0
```